# MySQL: WHERE-clause in query with COUNT and GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

For each category used for my adverts i want to show the total count of adverts.

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    categories_adverts.category,
    COUNT(adverts.id) AS numberOfAdverts
FROM adverts
LEFT JOIN categories_adverts
ON adverts.id_categories_adverts=categories_adverts.id
GROUP BY category ASC
```

I am struggling with including a WHERE clause which specificies that only those adverts are shown whose duration is still valid. I tried to include the following clause between "FROM adverts" and "LEFT JOIN ...":

```
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(now(),adverts.stamp_created))<=adverts.duration
```

So the whole query would like like this, but this does NOT work:

```
SELECT
    categories_adverts.category,
    COUNT(adverts.id) AS numberOfAdverts
FROM adverts
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(now(),adverts.stamp_created))<=adverts.duration
LEFT JOIN categories_adverts
ON adverts.id_categories_adverts=categories_adverts.id
GROUP BY category ASC
```

What is wrong about the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WHERE clause should be after your joins and before grouping and ordering,
like this:

```sql
SELECT
    categories_adverts.category,
    COUNT(adverts.id) AS numberOfAdverts
FROM adverts
LEFT JOIN categories_adverts
ON adverts.id_categories_adverts=categories_adverts.id
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(now(),adverts.stamp_created))<=adverts.duration
GROUP BY category ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause comes after the `join`s

```
SELECT c.category,
       COUNT(a.id) AS numberOfAdverts
FROM adverts a
LEFT JOIN categories_adverts c ON a.id_categories_adverts = c.id
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(now(),a.stamp_created)) <= a.duration
GROUP BY c.category ASC
```